# Barra branca no topo do wordpress

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theme

Estou montando um tema no wordpress 4.1 e estou passando por um problema no Chrome.

Aparece uma barra branca no topo do meu layout e não estou conseguindo retira-la! Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando vou ver no developer do Chrome, aparece como se meu `header` estivesse dentro do `body`! Meio louco isso, nunca tinha acontecido! Já no Firefox está perfeito!

- Já desativei a `navbar` do wordpress no perfil do usuário
- Ativei e coloquei as tags para ela aparece e não saiu!
- Já tentei de tudo!

Meu `Header.php`

```css
html, body{ margin:0; padding:0;}

.container-fluid {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.bgHeader {
 width: 100%;
 background: #000;
 background: url(imagens/bg_header.jpg) no-repeat top center;
 height: 167px;
 background-size: cover;
}
.header-config {
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.formSearch {
 margin-top: 40px;
}
.midiasSociaisHeader {
 margin-top: 35px;
}
.midiasSociaisHeader img {
 margin-left: 15px;
}
.menu-config {
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #16b2fd, #0383f1);
 height: 60px;
 margin-top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tediado</title>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js para apoio IE8 de elementos HTML5 e consultas de mídia -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js não funcionar se você visualizar a página via arquivo:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<header class="bgHeader">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row header-config">
      <div class="col-xs-3"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imagens/logo_tediado.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="Logo Tediado"></div>
      <div class="col-xs-5 formSearch">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
          </span> </div>
        <!-- /input-group --> 
        
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 midiasSociaisHeader"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imagens/facebook.gif" class="img-responsive pull-left" alt="Facebook Tediado"> <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imagens/twitter.gif" class="img-responsive pull-left" alt="Facebook Tediado"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Estou usando o bootstrap, não sei se é ele que está fazendo isso! Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1):

Muito possivelmente isso é porque um dos arquivos (não necessariamente o header) está com o `UTF-8 BOM`, [veja este outro caso no Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289747/switching-to-utf-8-white-spaces-appeared-on-top-of-html-pages-and-at-some-other).

Infelizmente remover isto irá depender do editor que está usando, mas em geral deve salvar o arquivo em `UTF-8` sem o uso do `BOM`.

### Usando PHPStorm:

1. Clique na pasta raíz do site com o botão direito.
2. Clique em "Remove BOM".

> Isso será aplicado para todos os arquivos do site, mas pode fazer isso individualmente.

### Usando Dreamweaver:

1. Abra o documento (ex. header.php)
2. Clique em "Salvar Como..."
3. Clique em "Opções de Unicode..."
4. Mantenha "Incluir assinatura Unicode (BOM)" desmarcado.
5. Clique em "OK".
6. Salve o arquivo.

**Se não usar nenhum desses editores sugiro que procure por como remover o "BOM" com o software que utiliza. :)**

Answer (score -1):

No próprio `<body>` coloque os parâmetros marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"

Answer (score -2):

Aconteceu algo parecido no meu site quando logado em admin.
O problema era que eu havia excluido, sem querer a função wp_footer()